# websites in which I can look for professors in specific field

Tags: phd, professorship

I am looking for useful websites like "findmyprof.org" in which I can search and find professors who work on specific field, categorized by country. The problem with "findmyprof.org" is that it does not separate European country.

Answer (score 3):

The instruction of *findmyprof.org* states:

> the structor is "keyword +country website code"
>   example: Climate change +ac.uk --> search only websites located in england

I searched for

> atmospheric science +.ch

and received results only for Switzerland.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use findmyprof.org website, the search query result list down the websites that matches your request. Note that you can set a window size for the first 10 or 50 professors in that domain. From that list you can lookup the hyperlinks and by looking at the end of that links, you can assume if it in uk or us ...etc.